# Chat box scroll bar not updating with new messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, livechat

I have a chat box which works well. It fetches the messages between two users and positions the scroll bar at the bottom until the user scrolls up. When a user sends a new message, the scroll bar jumps to the bottom and the new message is shown.

```
<script>
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var scrolled;
function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      //fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#messages").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      //chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 500); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time
      if(!scrolled){
        $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
        scrolled=true;
      }

    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#messages").on('scroll',function(){
        scrolled=true;
    });
 fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
      scrolled=false;
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    fetch_chat(); 
  });

setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();
}, 500);

  $("#sub").click(function() {

    var text = $("#text").val();

    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
       $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

I am using `setInterval()` to refresh `fetch_chat()` every time so that the user who is chatting sees the new message. The hiccup is that the `setInterval()` displays the chatbox, which I want to be displayed only when a user clicks on a name. The second thing is that when user 'a' sends a message to user 'b', the scroll bar remains at the bottom and the new text is shown on a's side but the scroll bar doesn't move to the bottom on b's side.

Comment: Hi just a comment.. you might want to make sure that you html encode the message text. not sure if you are doing that in your server code but if you drop text from text inputs onto a users screen using .html someone can do script injection.

Comment: also what you need to do is just not display the chat box when in SerInterval but display the chat box when a user click on a name. Then just make sure that the scroll bar goes to the bottom on B's side. The code is not going to write itself, you already said what you need to do so go and write the code for it.